# Visibility of parent node affects opacity of children nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'd like to implement a checkbox that enables/disables the hierarchy of my compound layout. It seems that the visibility of a parent node affects to its children. I've also tried opacity but it seems the same. Is there a way to get around this? Below you can find my code.

```
  //Turn on/off the hierarchy 

  $("#hierarchy-check").on("change",function(){
    if(this.checked) {
      not_childless.css({visibility:'visible'});
      childless.css({visibility:'visible'});
    } 
    else {
      not_childless.css({visibility:'hidden'});
      childless.css({visibility:'visible'});

    }  
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution for now based on the use of the [`eles.move()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/graph-manipulation/eles.move) function. When the hierarchy is enabled again I got some problems connecting childless nodes so I just remove the entire graph and add it again. Probably, it is not the ideal solution but it works ok for now. Below it is my code. Variables `not_childless` and `childless` are calculated before this event in my code.

```
     $("#hierarchy-check").on("change",function(){
    if(this.checked) {
     cy.elements().remove();
     childless.removeClass('hierarchyDisabled');
     cy.add(all_elements);
    } 
    else {
      for(let i=0; i < childless.length; i++) {
       childless[i].move({parent:null}); //I remove the current parent of the node but I keep the position
       childless.addClass('hierarchyDisabled'); //This is just some styling that I add
      }
      not_childless.remove();
    }  
  });
```